# C# How to update desired twin property of an Azure IoT Hub device

Tags: c#, azure, iot

I have registered the devices in IoT and the client application (device) can update reported twin properties. Now, I have to update desired twin properties from back end application (in C#). Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the way to update desired tags.

```
RegistryManager registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
var twin = await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(device.Id);
var patch = "{ \"properties\": { \"desired\": { \"configVersion\" : 3.1 } } }"; //json string
await registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(device.Id, tags, twin.ETag);
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this is by updating the desired [TwinCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.shared.twincollection?view=azure-dotnet) directly.

```
using (var manager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString("Your IoT Hub ConnectionString"))
{
   var twin = await manager.GetTwinAsync("your device id");
   twin.Properties.Desired["YourProperty"] = "some value";
   await manager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, twin, twin.ETag);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/iot-hub/Samples/service/JobsSample/JobsSample.cs) on GitHub.  And here's a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-twin-getstarted#create-the-service-app).

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
public async Task UpdateDesiredProperties(string deviceId)
{
    var twin = await _registryManager.GetTwinAsync(deviceId);

    var patch =
        @"{
        properties: {
            desired: {
              customKey: 'customValue'
            }
        }
    }";

    await _registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, patch, twin.ETag);
}
```

Comment: Both of these samples do not change desired twin property.

Comment: This one does: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/iot-hub/Samples/service/RegistryManagerSample/RegistryManagerSample.cs#L135